# I am trying to send array of images but I am unable to get data in server using nodejs

Tags: node.js

Here is my plunker link
https://plnkr.co/edit/0I0bbymoekwpyIXSOFJu?p=catalogue

I want to know how upload array of images.

For the single file, it's working, for multiple files I want to know what I need to write in node js.

My code

```
router.route('/events')
.post(upload.single('event_image'),function(req,res){

console.log('**Inside create events**');
console.log(":req.body",req.body);
console.log(":req.fileeeeeee",req.body);
var event = new Event();
event.name = req.body.name;
event.description = req.body.description;
event.location = req.body.location;
event.startdate = req.body.startdate;
event.enddate = req.body.enddate;
event.tagline = req.body.tagline;
event.password = req.body.password;
event.passcode = getEventPasscode();
event.uid = req.body.user_id;
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `upload.array('event_images', 20)` (20 is maxCount) instead of `upload.single('event_image')`

EDIT:
Here is a code snippet that shows working route in node.js

```
router.post('/upload',
 function(req, res) {
  upload.array('event_images', 20),
  function(req, res) {
    _.each(req.files, file => {
      console.log(file.path);
      console.log(file.name);
    });
    res.json();
  }
);
```

Comment: Could you please show me on plunker because I tried but I am getting error @Dominik Dragičević

Comment: Can you please provide me more details about your error?

Comment: I am getting this thing in console @Dominik Dragičević
event_image: '[object File]'

Comment: Can't really tell much from that message. I edited my answer and added node.js code snippet. Also, make sure you renamed `event_image ` to `event_image `

Comment: Yeah but I am not getting the error is from front end side or backend @Dominik Dragičević

Comment: Well, check your Network tab in browser. If request responses with valid http response, the error is on the frontend.